# Trying to find piece ID on instructions w/ no ID

Tags: piece-information

[image: Lego angled plate piece with each side 1x1. The top part has a hole to flaten out the top of a lego brick and the side hole is an inverted tab.]

I've gotten online instructions and the above piece is required, but annoyingly the piece ID is not in the instructions and I can't find it on any lego websites. I just want to know what the piece ID is.

Answer (score 3):

This is the ID 4211760 which in the LEGO movie sets holds the piece of resistance in place on Emmet's back. See for example instructions of set 70801 (Melting Room).

Bricklink lists it as "Minifig, Neck Bracket with Back Stud" (42446).

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use app for Android (or iPhone) for finding necessary piece.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.betab.partsguideforlegotechnic

Comment: Hmm... This app reacts a bit oddly, and I couldn't find a search function. There is a lot to improve before I switch from browser based Bricklink to this app.